# Parent container not expanding to child elements

Tags: html, css, formatting

I have a bunch of vertically aligned tab items in which and I can't seem to get the parent container (the `<a href...>` in my HTML) to expand to cover the child elements. I've tried using a `<br style="clear: both">` and `overflow: hidden;`but the first didn't do anything and the second just cut it off (using auto just added a scroll bar, which doesn't help) any thoughts on how to fix it?

HTML sample:

```
<li class="active">
                                            <a href="#pane1a" data-toggle="tab">
                                                <div class="preview-box">
                                                    <img class="preview-image" src="img/monestary_floorplan.png">
                                                    <p id="previewcarousel1a"></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#pane1b" data-toggle="tab">
                                                <div class="preview-box">
                                                    <img class="preview-image" src="img/bkg-img-home2.jpg">
                                                    <p id="previewcarousel1b"></p>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </li>
```

CSS:

```
.preview-box {
  width: 90px;
  height: 80px;
  /*border: 2px solid red;*/
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.preview-image {
  display: block;
  width: 75px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 4px solid #84be46;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
.preview-items p{
  color: #84be46;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

The whole site can be seen [here](http://shalu.miketissenbaum.com/place2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to your `a` element seems to solve your problem. You may have adjust padding/margin, though.

Comment: Sorry for going dark... This didn't seem to really work either (I actually had a bottom margin of 40px that I hadn't included in my css above). I tried at a friend's suggestion to do `display:table` which at least gave it a a height and width, but it's still not expanding to the entire p element.

Comment: You have deffined a height of 80px to `.preview-box`, that's what is cutting the `p` elements inside it.

Comment: Awesome tacensi! That was my problem.