# Parent element background is cut off if child content is wider than browser width

Tags: css

On a simple markup:

```
<div class="line">
    <div class="content_width">Content</div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
.line {
    background: yellow;
}
.content_width {
    width: 500px;
}
```

yellow background is wide as a browser window, so if window width is less than 500 and you scroll to the right you can see it was cut off. How to make browser render this correctly? [Test Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juak14h1/)

I think the `.line` should, as a parent element, take the maximum width of its children, but maybe I am wrong. I could set the width to the `.line`, too, but I would like to see more elegant solution, without setting additional widths, because the site is responsive and this is only an IE8 issue.

I thought first this was an IE problem, but I see now same happens in other browsers. I could not notice that because the site is responsive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parent container not expanding to child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977722/parent-container-not-expanding-to-child-elements)

Comment: Not quite, that was inline link, here we have a block element issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try giving a:

```
display: inline-block;
```

To the `.line` class.

While I know this works, I can't point you to an official documentation why it does. Perhaps someone else can come up with an explanation + better solution.

Comment: Well indeed it [works](http://jsfiddle.net/juak14h1/1/)! Heaven know why... would also like to hear an explanation. Thanks man.